# Does google-visualization API refresh included fonts?

Tags: javascript, fonts, google-visualization, google-font-api

I have been doing an application which uses google-chart, google-fonts and awesome-fonts APIs. My main font is from google-fonts, I include them inside `<head>` tag, as well as the awesome-fonts.

However, when I use google-charts, fonts seems to be refreshed after the charts are loaded. By refresh, I mean, they seem like disappear and reload in a second. This makes my application seems weird. I didn't like it, and I'm not sure that google-charts is doing this effect.

here is my codesnippet to load google-charts;

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  function drawChart() {

      var best_letters_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          JSON.parse('{{ best_letters|safe }}')
      );

      var worst_letters_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          JSON.parse('{{ worst_letters|safe }}')
      );

      var best_letters_options = {
          title: 'Top Rated Hiragana Letters',
          width: 450,
          height: 240,
          isHtml: true,
          hAxis: {title: 'Letters', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
      };

      var worst_letters_options = {
          title: 'Worst Rated Hiragana Letters',
          width: 450,
          height: 240,
          isHtml: true,
          hAxis: {title: 'Letters', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
      };

      var best_letters_chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('best_letters_div'));
      best_letters_chart.draw(best_letters_data, best_letters_options);

      var worst_letters_chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('worst_letters_div'));
      worst_letters_chart.draw(worst_letters_data, worst_letters_options);

      $("#loader").hide();

  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

If I comment the lines which draws the charts ( `best_letters_chart.draw(best_letters_data, best_letters_options);` and `worst_letters_chart.draw(worst_letters_data, worst_letters_options);` ) my fonts are rendered one time, but well, the charts are not displayed with this time.

Why this is happening? I'm quite curious about this. If someone has any idea, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Hi there BrOSs, I figured out that it was about firebug on my firefox. When I close firebug it works smoothly, don't know why but it's not about google's api. thanks for your interest anyway.